# How server side events are called in .NET

Tags: asp.net

I am a beginner to .NET, I have some doubts in my mind. Can anybody help me to sort out?

1. When a user requests for a file(*.ASPX), The request first goes to IIS server and with the help of Handlers and modules it finds the type of file that need to be processed and sent back to the client. But while displaying on the cilent machine the content of the .ASPX file will be displayed as HTML controls. How are the events generated at the client side and sent back to the server?
2. I know runat=server tells the control will be processed at serverside.
   But every time why we need to write "runat=server". Is there any ASP.NET control which runs at client side?

Comment: Thank you all for the guidence...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are starting with .NET web development, ASP.NET MVC is the way to go IMO

an ASP.NET server control that is generating client events in the browser is exercising standard dom events via javascript code that gets injected into the page that is sent from the web server. try view page source from any browser to see what is actually generated and the picture will become more clear.

essentially **runat=server** is telling the ASP.NET parser to process the tag and generate some special HTML output for the page. see [GvS's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8642399/960184) in this thread of how client events for these controls are converted to a form POST that is handled on the server.

> http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_intro.asp
>
> How Does ASP.NET Work?
>
> When a browser requests an HTML file, the server returns the file When
> a browser requests an ASP.NET file, IIS passes the request to the
> ASP.NET engine on the server The ASP.NET engine reads the file, line
> by line, and executes the scripts in the file Finally, the ASP.NET
> file is returned to the browser as plain HTML
>
> also see
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_controls.asp
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_events.asp

Answer (score 3):

When you tell a "tag" to `runat="server"`, you tell the server to register the tag. Now the tag is included in the control/tag tree on the server, and can be found ont the server: When an event is fired, or attributes or contents is changed server side.

Client side events, are silently converted to a form POST. Together with some extra information, like the ID of the control, and the type of event.

Since your tag is registered on the server, it has an ID, that is also transferred to the client (look at the html source). This tree is build, (by parsing the .aspx file) before the event is "fired". Using this id, you can find the tag in the server-side control/tag tree, and run the method that is used to handle the event.

Using these technique, and a lot of ViewState, Asp.Net tries to deny the stateless nature of HTTP. At first this looks like a good idea, IMHO its better not to fight with nature. Currently ASP.Net MVC feels more naturally.

Answer (score 0):

These event just raised by server-side controllers ,when you click on a asp button , event information be captured on the client and an event message transmitted to the server, via an `HTTP post`.i think these possible by some registered event on the server.when you page is loading , some events registered on you page framework , and the raised by http post request.

Look, one of the difference between the client side and server side controls is the server side are registered in server and you can save their state in a view state for example. when you click on a server side button , first its client side event raised and the the server side .note that because the server side controls event registered on the server , when you click on the button ,you page posted back.but the client side controls just are valid in client , and their event just raised for you web browser

need more help ? comment me to edit my answer
regard , Ali